# React Native top and bottom border with dashed style

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

I am trying to apply a border for a view on top and bottom only with a "dashed" style. But the borderStyle not working with borderTopWidth and borderBottomWidth. 
This is working,

```js
<View
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    padding: 16,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1
  }}>{...content...}</View>
```

This is not working,

```js
<View
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    padding: 16,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: 'red',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
  }}>{...content...}</View>
```

Is there any different way to achieve this style?

Comment: you added duplicated styling props. were the bottom two meant for `borderTopColor` and `borderTopWidth`?

Comment: I think this is a bug, as you can see here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24224

Comment: @kenmistry that was my typing mistake. Sorry, I will update this.

Answer (score 5):

Not an exact solution, but this hack works (example - for adding bottom border)

```js
<View style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}>
  <View style={{ borderStyle: 'dashed', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000', margin: -2, marginBottom: 0 }}>
    <Text>Some Data to be underlined</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Basically what we are doing is:

1. defining an outer container which hides the overflowing parts (data, items etc).
2. for inner container, we set it's margins so as to go beyond outer container dimensions

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

function Index(props) {
  return <View style={styles.container}></View>;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 126,
    height: 46,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 2,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderStyle: "dashed"
  }
});

export default Index;
```

Note: I have design it by [BuilderX](https://builderx.io/)

[image]

Comment: I've also tried this as your answer. But it didn't work. This may be a bug as mentioned by @Tim, please refer this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24224

Comment: Unsupported dashed / dotted border style together borderTopWith / borderBottomWith ....

Comment: You can refer this comment it will surely solve your problem https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24224#issuecomment-849496947